# Importing a variable from another script and keeping it updated

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, python-import

I have two `.py` scripts. `script1.py` and `script2.py`

I am importing few variables from `script2.py` like:

```
from script2 import variable1 as var1
```

which works fine.

But when I *update* `variable1` in `script2.py`, and then re-run `script1.py`, the update of `variable1` doesn't show up in `script1.py`. Why is that so?

The update of `variable1` shows up if I close IPython completely and then re-open IPython again. But I don't want to do this all the time as I need few plot's to be open.

I am using `IPython 1.2.1` and `Python 2.7.6` (if further info maybe needed).

Comment: `import` takes the file in this moment and does not check if the file checks later. Therefore you won't get updates on any functions or variables you update in your script2.py sourcefile. You could remove the imported packet with `del var1` and then import it again, I think that should work. And if you have to update your script2.py regularly maybe you need another approach, like writing your variable in a config file and always reload it from there.

Comment: @Memnon: Can you please elaborate as to how one can do the above solution you have mentioned?

Comment: You mean the approach using a config file?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to reload modules, though it doesn't seem to work well with aliasing. You can use [`reload(module_name)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload). As you'll see the docs note that your aliases wont be refreshed:

> If a module imports objects from another module using `from ... import
>   ...`, calling `reload()` for the other module does not redefine the
>   objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the
>   from statement, another is to use import and qualified names
>   (`module.*name*`) instead.

It instead suggests using

```
import script2 
script2.variable1
```

You could still alias, but you'd need to refresh the aliased names each time:

```
import script2
var1 = script2.variable1

...

reload(script2)
var1 = script2.variable1
```

If you didn't do this, `var1` would hold the old value.

You could however have a quick function to do this all at once if you think it's necessary (and if it is happening often)

```
def reload_script2():
    global var1
    reload(script2)
    var1 = script2.variable1
```

Note I use `global` here so that `var1` is modified in the global namespace, not just declared in that function. If you really only have one value you could use `return var1`, but I think this is a rare case where `global` is better.

Comment: so the `reload(script2)` should be in Ipython or should it be within `script1`?

Comment: @ThePredator In IPython, it's basically like re-importing the module again and overwriting it.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I did `import nbimporter
from importlib import reload
import gcoli
reload(gcoli)`

and then wanted to print a variable that was used in gcoli.ipynb file. How can I access the variable?

Using gcoli.varname doesn't work.

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi: If it's in the `gcoli.ipynb` file, try using `gcoli.ipynb.varname`

Answer (score 2):

For ipython, use the [`%load`](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-load) magic command:

```
In [1]: from a import x

In [2]: x
Out[2]: 20

# here go and change the content of a.py

In [3]: from a import x

In [4]: x
Out[4]: 20 # same value

In [5]: %load a.py

In [6]: # %load a.py
x = 22

In [7]: x
Out[7]: 22 # new value
```

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work! When I `%load script2.py` after updating `variable1`, it still seems to give the old value when I run `script1.py`

Comment: It will only give you the new value in the ipython interpreter (as shown in the answer), it will not automatically update the value in the file `script1.py`.

Comment: But that is what I want!! Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to change the variables often I think its not a good approach to write it to a python script but rather to a config file. There you could simple read it like this

```
def getVar(name):
    c = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
    c.read('config.cfg')
    return c.get('global',name)
```

While the variable is written in your `config.cfg` file like this:

```
[global]
var1 = 5
var2 = 10
```

You could also save it as JSON and just use a json reader instead of the config reader.

In the end you can get your variable with `getVar('var1')` and it will always be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier just to store the value in a file. For example, in the first script you would have:

```
myvar = 6

# do stuff

config_file = open('config.txt', 'w')
config_file.write(myvar)
config_file.close()
```

and in the second script you would have:

```
config_file_read = open('config.txt', 'r')
oldvar = int(config_file_read.read()) # you could also do float() (or any type)
config_file_read.close()

print oldvar

newvar = 5
config_file_write = open('config.txt', 'w') # this overwrites the contents of the file
config_file_write.write(str(newvar))
config_file_write.close()
```