# How to import the same module in a python file again when the module have some changes

Tags: python, python-import

I am building a python GUI to control some external devices. We can use two types of connections which have different commands to control the devices so I have to write two versions of code for the same function.

The following is a conceptual framework of my project:

```
rungui.py
guilibrary/
    __init__.py
    basic_functions.py
    advanced_functions.py
    ...
```

When the gui is first launched, basic_functions.py will run and detect which connection is in use, then return the corresponding function. Like this:

```
def readsomething():
    connection = searchconnection()
    if connection == 1:
        return readsthVersionA()
    else:
        return readsthVersionB()
```

And then advanced_functions.py will import readsomething() from basic_functions.py

I want to make the gui refreshable, i.e. I can use a button to re-init all the things without closing the gui. What I try is to write a function to destroy the gui and then run the function to launch the gui again.

However, when the advanced_functions.py imports basic_functions.py again, it simply skips this line. Seems that a module already imported cannot be imported again. So if I changed from connection type A to type B,readsomething() is still in version A.

I wonder if there is any solution to that. Thanks!

Comment: refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039631/importing-a-variable-from-another-script-and-keeping-it-updated). check if any solution there is what you need

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but it certainly sounds like basic object-oriented code is where your solution lies and self-modifying code definitely is not (and it very, very rarely is).

Comment: Oh, i think this is very useful. I will try, thanks a lot!

Comment: if you have to load again module then you have something wrong with your code. You should have code in function which you can run again instead of reloading module.